# select numbers in between "-" in R

Tags: r

I have a file named

```
gameofdice-017-1.txt
```

I was wondering how to use gsub to only select the 017?

This is probably a duplicate question, but I had a hard time trying to find the answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please describe the logic behind the extraction of the numbers, and provide a reproducible example with a list with more filenames, and desired output. For this single name, we might just hard-code "017"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We assume that the general case here is that there are exactly two minus signs and some digits between them.  If a character result is wanted then the characters between the minus signs may be non-digits.

**1)** Use read.table with a minus separator and pick out the 2nd field.  Omit the colclasses= argument if you want a numeric return value.

```
x <- "gameofdice-017-1.txt"
read.table(text = x, sep = "-", colClasses = "character")$V2
## [1] "017"
```

**2)** or with `sub` match each field and replace them with the capture group.  Omit the `as.numeric` if you want a character result "017"

```
as.numeric(sub(".*-(.*)-.*", "\\1", x))
## [1] 17
```

**3)** or trim non minus signs off the ends and then trim minus signs off the ends.  As above, remove the `as.numeric` if you want a character result.

```
as.numeric(trimws(trimws(x, whitespace = "[^-]"), whitespace = "-"))
## [1] 17
```

**4)** Replace each - with / to convert it to a path and then extract the directory name and then the basename which is the last portion of the remaining path.  Omit as.numeric if you want a character result.

```
as.numeric(basename(dirname(chartr("-", "/", x))))
## [1] 17
```

**5)** or extract the capture group (portion matched within parentheses)

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(x, "-(.*)-", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "017"
```

If you wanted a numeric result then

```
strapply(x, "-(.*)-", as.numeric, simplify = TRUE)
## [1] 17
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a capture group:

```
x <- "gameofdice-017-1.txt"
value <- gsub("^[^-]+-([^-]+)-[^-]+$","\\1",x)
```

The `[^-]` character classes match any character except `-`. The parentheses around the second `[^-]+` (matching one or more characters not equal to `-`) form a capture group, and `\\1` evaluates to the first (and only) capture group.

If you want the value as an integer, you can wrap the call in `as.integer(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyverse solutuon suitable for packet filename processing:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr) 

c("gameofdice-017-1.txt", 
"gameofdice-018-1.txt") %>%
str_split("-")  %>%
lapply(FUN = function(x) x[2]) %>%
unlist
```